Turkish transit visa
My friend holds a German travel document for refugees. Does she need a transit visa for less than 24 hours in Turkey, while traveling to Georgia?

Assuming she is travelling from Germany, and that her travel document is 1954 Convention, Timatic returns the following answer:

Visa required.


TWOV (Transit Without Visa)


Passengers transiting through Ankara (ESB), Antalya (AYT), Istanbul: Metropolitan Area (IST) and Sabiha Gokcen (SAW), or Izmir (ADB) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.


TWOV in Antalya (AYT) does not apply when transiting between terminals 1 and 2.

You can confirm the answer by inputting the correct documentation and trip details using the link above.
